# Truncatable primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Why only 11 ?

The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.

There are only eleven primes that are both truncatable from left to right and right to left.

Comment: Arguably there are fifteen if you include $2,3,5,7$

Answer (score 4):

Edit:

The original answer below is wrong, as so clearly explained by sundar below. However the method remains correct if one applies the same answer to the left truncatable primes, the right truncatable primes, and then intersects the two computed lists.

Original Answer:

If there are no $n$ digit primes with this property, then there are also no $n+1$ digit primes which this property. One can thus do an exhaustive search, and as soon as you search through all the $n$ digit primes and don't find a number with this property, you know you are done. Presumably your list will have 15 numbers on it, although I haven't checked.

Comment: > If there are no n digit primes with this property, then there are also no n+1 digit primes which this property. <
This doesn't seem right - the 11 truncatable primes are (23, 37, 53, 73, 313, 317, 373, 797, 3137, 3797, 739397) - there are no 5-digit truncatable primes, but there's a 6 digit one. This is because the intermediate ones only have to be truncatable from one direction - so 73839 is right-truncatable and 39397 is left-truncatable, but there doesn't need to be a 5-digit number that's one of the 11 truncatable primes, for there to be a 6-digit one.

Comment: @sundae: Indeed, you are correct.

Comment: 73839 was a typo, I meant to say 73939 there (and that one's only right truncatable). My basic point is simple: there is a 7 digit truncatable prime, but there's no 6 digit truncatable prime. So the statement I quoted from the answer is false. So, an exhaustive search on n-digit primes (and finding no both-truncatable prime) doesn't mean you are done, that algorithm will halt too early without finding 739397.

Comment: @sundar: Indeed, my first comment responding to you misunderstood your meaning (not just the typo). Please see my updated comment and answer.